# Getting visible content from the UIWebView in iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, xhtml

I am developing an epub ebook application, I loaded the xhtml file into `UIWebview` and also did the pagination, I need to display the bookmarked pages list with some text related to that particular page in the list, for this I need to get the text from `UIWebView`.

I tried the following `Javascript` API

`NSString *myText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];`

but its returing the complete html text, not the visible text of that particular webpage.

How can I get the only visible content from the `UIWebView`.
Any ideas how can I achieve this, please share your ideas

thank you in advance

shiva.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for it, if any one required please refer to below code.

```
function getElementFromPoint(x,y) {
    var str ="hello";
    var i = 0;
    var j = 20;
    var x1 = parseInt(x)+j;
    alert("x"+x1);
    for( i = 0 ;i < 1024;i += 2)
    {
        var element = document.elementFromPoint(x1,i);
        if(element.nodeName == "p" || element.nodeName == "h1" || element.nodeName == "h2"  || element.nodeName == "h3")
        {
            str = element.innerText.trim();
            if(str.length <= 3)
                continue;
            return str;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
 getElementFromPoint(x,y);
```

Comment: I had tried your code but it does not returns me the div tag, I had passes current x & y offset of webview scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Try`document.body.innerHTML` it will get the hmm code in the body. But it will still be HTML formatted.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply Jonathan, i tried it but its giving me the complete xhtml body content, i need only a part of xhtml content which is visible in the UIWebView.